# i want to extract any ID start with 740 and then extract the first 13 digits from it

Tags: r

i want to extract any ID start with 740 and then extract the first 13 digits from it

```
id <- c(
7401988456123452,
7401955456218,
740202045655545,
7401938152000,
740198845612314554
)
```

Comment: All those start with "740". Do you want 13 digits after the 740 or including the 740?

Comment: included 740 in 13 digits, i want to extract data frame achieve this condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `startsWith` and `substring`. If needed cast it back to numeric with `as.numeric`.

```
substring(id[startsWith(as.character(id), "740")], 1, 13)
#[1] "7401988456123" "7401955456218" "7402020456555" "7401938152000"
#[5] "7401988456123"
```

Comment: can i extract df using same code?

Comment: Just use `DF$column` on places where I used `id`.

Comment: its only gives id column but i need all data frame

Comment: Then use `i <- startsWith(as.character(DF$column), "740")` `cbind(DF[i,], substring(DF$column[i], 1, 13))`